# How do I say that I called someone?

Tags: english-to-japanese

For example if I wanted to say "I called bob", would it be something like "私は Bob の電話を呼びました"?

That sentence feels a little awkward and I'm not sure how to properly phrase it.

Comment: Why does it feel awkward to you?

Comment: I don't really have a reason, it just felt awkward to me when saying it out loud so I was wondering if there was a better way to say it.

Comment: That's okay, I was asking so that you could get an answer that meets your concerns better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「電{でん}話{わ}をかけた」is one option, and「電話（を）した」is another. There's also「電話を入{い}れた」, which tends to be used in more 'functional' contexts, like if the call was made to inform/notify the other party about something or in order to confirm something. You would use each of these after starting with「ボブに」in the given example. To convert these to somewhat more polite versions, you can replace the final「～た」 with「～ました」.

Comment: Is there a scenario where I would use した over かけた? Or vice versa.

Comment: 電話をかける sounds more elaborate / places more emphasis on the act of calling itself than 電話をする, which puts more emphasis on who you call or what you call about etc. 電話する without the を is the most casual option.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A way I learned to say this is ボブに電話をかけました。

The に indicates a "destination" in the same way ～に聞きました means asking ~ a question.

[jisho entry](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1%E3%82%92%E6%8E%9B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the に part, I got a bit confused when looking at the particle rules.